# APCu is not enabled ? Cant create fixtures

Tags: docker, symfony, dockerfile, symfony-3.3

I have a problem using the command:

**php bin / console d: f: l**

```
 [Symfony \ Component \ Cache \ Exception \ CacheException]
  APCu is not activated
```

While Symfony 3 recognizes acpu extension very well.
For information, I am on docker and I have successfully installed the ACPu extension.

Symfony detects the cache well but I don't know why the script doesn't want to start. I tried to take inspiration from other DockerFile but still the same problem.

My PHP DockerFile:

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm-alpine

MAINTAINER Zakariae Filali <filali.zakariae@gmail.com>
ARG TIMEZONE
ENV WORKDIR "/var/www/symfony"
ENV EXT_APCU_VERSION=5.1.17
RUN apk upgrade --update && apk --no-cache add \
    git autoconf tzdata openntpd libcurl curl-dev coreutils \
    libmcrypt-dev freetype-dev libxpm-dev libjpeg-turbo-dev libvpx-dev \
    libpng-dev libressl-dev libxml2-dev postgresql-dev icu-dev \
    yarn

RUN docker-php-source extract \
    # ext-apcu
    && mkdir -p /usr/src/php/ext/apcu \
    && curl -fsSL https://github.com/krakjoe/apcu/archive/v$EXT_APCU_VERSION.tar.gz | tar xvz -C /usr/src/php/ext/apcu --strip 1 \
    && docker-php-ext-install apcu \
    # cleanup
    && docker-php-source delete

RUN apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .build-dependencies $PHPIZE_DEPS \
        && pecl install apcu \
        && docker-php-ext-enable apcu \
        && pecl clear-cache \
        && apk del .build-dependencies

RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual build-dependencies icu-dev libxml2-dev freetype-dev libpng-dev libjpeg-turbo-dev g++ make autoconf

RUN docker-php-ext-configure intl \
    && docker-php-ext-configure opcache \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ \
    --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ --with-png-dir=/usr/include/ \
    --with-xpm-dir=/usr/include/

RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd iconv pdo pdo_mysql pdo_pgsql curl \
    bcmath mbstring json xml xmlrpc zip intl opcache


RUN yes '' | pecl install -f mcrypt
RUN echo "extension=mcrypt.so" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/mcrypt.ini

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/${TIMEZONE} /etc/localtime && echo ${TIMEZONE} > /etc/timezone \
&& printf '[PHP]\ndate.timezone = "%s"\n', ${TIMEZONE} > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/tzone.ini \
&& "date"


RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | \
    php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer


RUN rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* \
    && find / -type f -iname \*.apk-new -delete \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

RUN mkdir -p ${WORKDIR}
RUN chown www-data:www-data -R ${WORKDIR}
RUN version=$(php -r "echo PHP_MAJOR_VERSION.PHP_MINOR_VERSION;") \
    && curl -A "Docker" -o /tmp/blackfire-probe.tar.gz -D - -L -s https://blackfire.io/api/v1/releases/probe/php/alpine/amd64/$version \
    && mkdir -p /tmp/blackfire \
    && tar zxpf /tmp/blackfire-probe.tar.gz -C /tmp/blackfire \
    && mv /tmp/blackfire/blackfire-*.so $(php -r "echo ini_get ('extension_dir');")/blackfire.so \
    && printf "extension=blackfire.so\nblackfire.agent_socket=tcp://blackfire:8707\n" > $PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d/blackfire.ini \
    && rm -rf /tmp/blackfire /tmp/blackfire-probe.tar.gz


WORKDIR ${WORKDIR}

CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable apc for cli.
If you launch `php -i`, you should have something like that:

```
apc.coredump_unmap => Off => Off
apc.enable_cli => Off => Off
apc.enabled => On => On
apc.entries_hint => 4096 => 4096
apc.gc_ttl => 3600 => 3600
apc.mmap_file_mask => no value => no value
apc.preload_path => no value => no value
apc.serializer => php => php
apc.shm_segments => 1 => 1
apc.shm_size => 32M => 32M
apc.slam_defense => On => On
apc.smart => 0 => 0
apc.ttl => 0 => 0
apc.use_request_time => On => On
apc.writable => /tmp => /tmp
```

You can see `apc.enable_cli` is set to `Off`.

So, add this line to your Dockerfile:

```
RUN echo "apc.enable_cli=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-apcu.ini
```